# ng-change event not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a custom directive using Angular JS. I have a function inside the controller which i'm trying to call on an ng-change event from a text box. but the function is not getting called. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var delightMeterApp = angular.module('delightMeterApp', []);
    delightMeterApp.directive('delightMeter', function () {
        return {
            scope: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div id="delightmeter"></div>',
            link: function (scope, element) {


                newdiv = jQuery('<div/>', {
                    id: 'delightContainer',
                    class: 'singlenote'
                }).appendTo('#delightmeter');

                var appendstring = "";
                appendstring += "<svg width='500px' height='300px' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg>'";
                appendstring += "<g>";
                appendstring += "<text x='100' y='220' fill='black'>0</text>";
                appendstring += "<text x='300' y='220' fill='black'>100</text>";
                appendstring += "<path class='arc' id='arc1' d='' />";
                appendstring += "<path class='arc' id='arc2' d='' />";
                appendstring += "<path class='arc' id='arc3' d='' />";
                appendstring += "<path class='arc' id='arc4' d='' />";
                appendstring += "<path class='arc' id='arc5' d='' />";
                appendstring += "<g class='needleset'>";
                appendstring += "<circle class='needle-center' cx='200' cy='200' r='5'></circle>";
                appendstring += "<path class='needle' d='M 195 198 L 200 100 L 205 202'></path>";
                appendstring += "</g></g></svg>";

                newdiv.append(appendstring);

                document.getElementById("arc1").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -90, -56));
                document.getElementById("arc2").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -54, -20));
                document.getElementById("arc3").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -18, 16));
                document.getElementById("arc4").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, 18, 52));
                document.getElementById("arc5").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, 54, 90));

                function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
                    var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees - 90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

                    return {
                        x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
                        y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
                    };
                }

                function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {

                    var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
                    var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

                    var arcSweep = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";

                    var d = [
                        "M", start.x, start.y,
                        "A", radius, radius, 0, arcSweep, 0, end.x, end.y
                    ].join(" ");

                    return d;
                }
            },
            template: '<div id="delightmeter"></div>',
            controller: "delightMeterController"

        };
    });
    delightMeterApp.controller('delightMeterController', function ($scope) {

        $scope.fun = function () {
            alert("called");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Following is my HTML

```
<div ng-app="delightMeterApp" ng-controller="delightMeterController">
    <delight-meter ng-model="delightScore"></delight-meter>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" ng-change="fun()" />
</div>
```

Is it correct to use same controller both for the custom directive and the input control. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you using the controller in your directive anyway?

Comment: Any console errors ?

Comment: I'm new to angular JS. I got answer for another problem in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865129/angular-js-javascript-not-working-inside-custom-directive-template - the answer said to use controller for the custom directive to include javascript in it

Comment: @OmriAharon No console errors

Comment: Try removing the controller, btw you should never directly manipulate the DOM in your controller, that should only happen in directives

Comment: @NexusDuck is there any other way to create custom directive ? My template will have lots of Javascript. So i cannot include it as a template. I tried including it as templateUrl which also gave me many problems. This seemed to work somehow so far.

Comment: @NexusDuck if i remove the controller where will i place the javascript?

Comment: @SoorajChandran I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but writing code in a directive usually happens in a link function

Comment: you have buttons or input, you need to use controller.

Comment: @NexusDuck What you said works fine. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooraj,

Like what NexusDuck says you should never manipulate the DOM in your controller. I have reorganized your code to have the DOM manipulation in the Directive and the Controller to just call the Rotate Needle function. The Rotate Needle function does get called in the Directive.

This the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="delightMeterController">
<delightmeter delight-meter-reference='delightMeterReference'></delightmeter>
<input id="txtScore" type="text" ng-model="delightScore" ng-change="delightMeterReference.RotateNeedle(delightScore)" />{{delightScore}}
</div>
```

This is your Directive:

```
.directive('delightmeter', function () {
    function link($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        var meter = $element[0];
        console.log(meter);

        document.getElementById("arc1").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -90, -56));
        document.getElementById("arc2").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -54, -20));
        document.getElementById("arc3").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -18, 16));
        document.getElementById("arc4").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, 18, 52));
        document.getElementById("arc5").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, 54, 90));

        function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
            var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees - 90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

            return {
                x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
                y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
            };
        }

        function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {

            var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
            var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);
            var arcSweep = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";
            var d = [
                "M", start.x, start.y,
                "A", radius, radius, 0, arcSweep, 0, end.x, end.y
            ].join(" ");
            return d;
        }

        function RotateNeedle(delightScore) {
            console.log(delightScore);
            $('.needleset').css({
                "transform": "rotate(" + delightScore + "deg)",
                "transform-origin": "50% 95%"
            });
        }

        if ($scope.delightMeterReference) {
            $scope.delightMeterReference.RotateNeedle = function (delightScore) {
                RotateNeedle(delightScore);
            }
        }
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'components/comp01/comp01.html',
        scope: {
            delightMeterReference: '='
        },
        link: link
    };
})
```

And this is your Controller

```
.controller('delightMeterController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.delightScore = 0;
    $scope.delightMeterReference = {};


})
```

Thanks,
Shivas